# How to get the URL of the hyperlink in Selenium driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get URL's of hyperlinks present on current page using Selenium Web driver. Can anyone help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get href value (WebDriver)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579007/get-href-value-webdriver)

Comment: Did you google this before posting? This has been asked and answered a bunch of times. In the future, before posting google your own question and look for an answer. Try out the answer and then if it still doesn't work, come here and post the code you tried, what the result was, and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 5):

To get the URL of all the links on a page, you can store all the elements with tagname 'a' in a WebElement list and then you can fetch the href attribute to get the link of each WebElement.

you can refer to the following code :

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); //This will store all the link WebElements into a list

    for(WebElement ele: links) // This way you can take the Url of each link
    {
    String url = ele.getAttribute("href"); //To get the link you can use getAttribute() method with "href" as an argument 
    System.out.println(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get them from the href attribute using `getAttribute()` (assuming you are in java):

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"))
String url = link.getAttribute("href")
```